# $\vec H$ calculation, given $\vec J$, exercise confusion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

> I would like to calculate $\vec H $ at every point, given the following pattern (which extends infinitely at $x$ and $y$ directions).

[image]

(we are viewing at $xz$ plane)
$$
\vec J(x,y,z)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{J_0z}{h}\hat{x}&\mbox{, if }z \in (-h,h)\\\\
\;\;\; \vec0&\mbox{, else }
\end{cases}
$$

Because of symmetry we can see that $\vec H = \vec H(z)$ and also,
$$
\begin{cases}
H_x(z) &= -H_x(-z) \\
H_z(z) &= -H_z(-z) \\
H_y(z) &= \; \; \; H_y(-z)
\end{cases}
$$
where $\vec H = (H_x,H_y,H_z)$.

Combining the above with both point and integral form of Maxwell's equations I ended up at the following:
$$
\vec H(x,y,z)= \hat{y} H_y(z)=
\begin{cases}
\biggl ( c-\dfrac{J_0z^2}{2h} \biggr ) \hat{y} &\mbox{, if }z \in (-h,h)\\\\
\biggl (c-\dfrac{J_0h}{2} \biggr ) \hat{y} &\mbox{, else }
\end{cases}
$$
where $c$ is a constant.

> I cannot find how to calculate that constant. I tried to see if there is any point where $\vec H = \vec 0$ without success. Please help.

(the following figure corresponds to my question to an answer bellow)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant $c$ is arbitrary. You can always immerse your system in a constant, externally imposed, field $H_y=c$. "Externaly imposed"  means that the mechanism  producing this external field is  very far away. The uniform field has ${\rm curl}\, {\bf H}_{\rm external}=0$, so it does not mess up your solution.

If the only currents in the universe are those in the problem, then you can safely set $c=J_0h/2$ so that there is no field outside the region where the excplicily given current is located.

Comment: Thank you! There is one thing that confuses me. If we suppose there are no external currents and set $c=0$ then $\vec H(0)=\vec 0$. However, form the second figure I added we see that $Η_y(0)$ must be positive because of the contribution of infinitesimal currents $dI$ that cause $dH$ in $y$ direction. Is anything wrong in this observational argument?

Comment: Also, if this argument is correct, doesn't that mean that $H_y(0)$ has a specific value, so $c=H_y(0)$ has as specific value as well?

Comment: Sorry! My bad! it  is $c=J_0 h/2$ that gives no external field (and no field oustide the given current distrubtion)  Then $H_y(z=0)$ is $J_0h/2$ as your drawing shows.Ive edited my answer to correct the error.